# Gitlab Runner to push files generated on the fly back to repo

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a repository in GitLab, this repo has some files along with .gitlab-ci.yml file. On pushing/submitting changes and with the help of .gitlab-ci.yml file, code in this repository generates new files on the fly. Is there any way to push the files that got generated on the fly back to the repository upon the completion of the pipeline job?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes of course you can use git commands to add your files, commit and push them